# Display both data in different fields in QGIS attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, latitude-longitude, display

In my attribute table I have `lat_1`, `long_1` and `lat_2`, `long_2` in the same row. How can I display both at the same time. Is their any solution for that in QGIS.

`lat_1`, `long_1` are main location

`lat_2`, `long_2` are entry point location

That means in attribute table field names should be unique right. So it will display only x and y. But in my attribute table their are entry points (lat, long) they are also coordinates. So I want the both x & y (main and entry) displayed.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. Instead, edit the previous one. The other question is in reopen queue. It will be reopened soon.

Comment: @babel Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @KadirŞahbaz I am unable to edit the question that's why I repost the same question by changing it

Comment: @Kadir Şahbaz: sorry, I did not realize that the other question was asked by the same user. Bruno B: indeed, you should edit your first question to comply with the comments made there. Don't simply ask the same question again.